# comparing Empty Value and NULL in C

Tags: arrays, c, graph, null

I have a question  - how people normally compare a value with `NULL` or whitespace in an array?

things start here:
I have created a empty pointer array - simply use the code:

```
 Vertex *VertexArray[15];
```

[image: in my debug process, it looks like this]

and now I would love to compare another `Vertex` node with this array - say `1st` one. - `VertexArray[0]`

[image]

But I cant...The system won't allow me to do that...
it shows me error:
[image]

I used this argument -

```
if ( VertexArray[A->BusStopNumber]->Vinfo== NULL || VertexArray[A->BusStopNumber]->Vinfo->BusStopNumber == A->BusStopNumber)//both A and B are not in the graph
```

Did I do `smh` wrong? or How should I fix it?

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Comparing with null is done exactly as you do it

Comment: What does "The system wont allow me to do that" mean?

Comment: Note that if `VertexArray[A->BusStopNumber]` is null or invalid then you may not attempt to access members of the hypothetical pointed-to object.  Specifically, evaluating `VertexArray[A->BusStopNumber]->Vinfo` produces undefined behavior in such cases.  To avoid that, you may null-check `VertexArray[A->BusStopNumber]` first.

Comment: Hey John, Thanks for reply - I've updated my question :)

Comment: @JohnBollinger Hey man - I think you are right - I need NULL check 1st!!!!

Comment: Please do not present images of text.  Copy & paste the text *as text*.  Also, please present an actual [mre].  Code fragments such as you have presented are difficult to interpret out of context.  For example, the code you describe as creating an empty pointer array does not do that, but what, exactly, it *does* do depends on where it appears in your code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you. I will do it next time!

Comment: @JohnBollinger Hey Mate, Sorry for asking, But I am wondering is there any way to initialise the whole array - set all element to NULL? Or I didn't creat my array correctly? how come there are element that is not NULL?

Comment: `malloc()` does not initialize the memory it allocates for you, you will need to do this yourself. So you will have all kind of contents. There are numerous ways to do it, explicitely with a loop, with `memset()`, ... Or you  use `calloc()` that zeroes the memory it allocates for you. Please read the documentation, and use your favorite web serach engine.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a question - how people normally compare a value with Null or whitespace in an array?

NULL and whitespace are two very different things. NULL is the standard value of a pointer that doesn't point to anything meaningful.

In your code, `VertexArray[A->BusStopNumber]->Vinfo` causes a segfault because `VertexArray[A->BusStopNumber]` may be NULL, `->Vinfo` is trying to access memory relative to NULL, which doesn't exist.

You can fix this by checking if `VertexArray[A->BusStopNumber]` is NULL first.